# What Github "Releases" feature is good for?

Tags: git, github

How do i suppose to use it?
I can just create separated branch called, say, "production", and push data there on each release.

I assume, people may use this feature, when they are doing regular "Merge" of new feateures instead of "Squash and Merge" and therefore their main branches get populated with lots of commits that are not production-ready. But, if i'm always doing "Squash and merge" of fully tested features and therefore each commit in my "production" branch is actually production-ready, then i do not have such problems and production branch is actually my list of releases, right? In this case "Releases" feature becomes useless.

Sorry if you think this question is too broad - please lmk in comments what exactly need to be specified more in order to answer to this conceptual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current workflow is close to 'continues development'. Release branches are used in others git flows like 'feature branches'. Idea is to track release numbers to got reference point in the future.

Git workflows tutorial:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a DOI for your releases on GitHub if you want to make your code/program citable.

[Making Your Code Citable](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/)

I wanted to post this as comment, but I don't have enough reputation in the moment.